# how can I repeat a background image according to the text size (dynamically coming by parsing) in android

Tags: android, image, android-emulator, android-layout

I am facing a problem in my android app. I have to dynamically find the height of the text description coming from parsing the xml and show it on an imageview(background image).

I have to repeat the backround image by finding the total height of the text.

So, Please help me that how can we find the text height dynamically and repeat the  background image according to that height.

Thanks.

Comment: you should post your xml layout here. What you have implemented so far?

Comment: I dont have any idea that how to solve this problem. So I dont have any code yet.

Comment: So you want the background of a TextView to have a tiled/repeating background image?

Comment: yes  and also I have to find the height of the text details dynamically coming from xml.

Comment: @Dinesh then you should create a 9-patch background image and place inside the listview item. More about 9-patch image at:http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: Can u kindly give me few codes to understand it in a more proper manner.Actually I could not get you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no answer for this question.
I tried and almost did it in the following way:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    String description="hello how r u this project is meant for android to calculate " +
            "the size of text and can dyanamically set the image height according to the text";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        int length_count=description.length();
        int window_width=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        int lines=(length_count*14)/(window_width-30);
        Log.v("length",""+length_count);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.project_dess_box_mid);     
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);     
        bitmapDrawable.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);     
        LinearLayout layout =  (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear1);
        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text01);
        tv.setLines(lines);
        tv.setText(description);
        layout.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable); 


    }
}
```

I posted  this as it may be helpful for others too.